# Errors while implementing Chromecast in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, chromecast

I seem to have a problem implementing `ChromeCast` features in a project of mine.
I have been trying to implement the `GCKDeviceScannerListener` Singleton Class on a `UIViewController`, however its delegate methods are not getting called.

The `deviceDidComeOnline` method of `GCKDeviceScannerListener` never gets called.

Instead I have a bunch of error displayed by the `chromeCast` logger as followed:

```
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_loadFromCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file:///Users/martin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/318D2E15-C4B0-47D2-97AF-CD560A6063AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/C117BB98-88DA-4586-B119-0683DAD82FEB/Library/Caches/gck_nearby_devices.plist doesn't exist.

+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_loadFromCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file:///Users/martin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/318D2E15-C4B0-47D2-97AF-CD560A6063AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/C117BB98-88DA-4586-B119-0683DAD82FEB/Library/Caches/gck_network_cache.plist doesn't exist.

scanning started

+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_deleteCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file:///Users/martin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/318D2E15-C4B0-47D2-97AF-CD560A6063AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/C117BB98-88DA-4586-B119-0683DAD82FEB/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache.plist doesn't exist.

+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_deleteCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file:///Users/martin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/318D2E15-C4B0-47D2-97AF-CD560A6063AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/C117BB98-88DA-4586-B119-0683DAD82FEB/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v1.plist doesn't exist.

+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_deleteCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file:///Users/martin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/318D2E15-C4B0-47D2-97AF-CD560A6063AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/C117BB98-88DA-4586-B119-0683DAD82FEB/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v2.plist doesn't exist.

+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_loadFromCacheWithName:] - Device cache file 
file:///Users/martin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/318D2E15-C4B0-47D2-97AF-CD560A6063AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/C117BB98-88DA-4586-B119-0683DAD82FEB/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v3.plist doesn't exist
```

I can't seem to figure out why I have these errors. But it seems that the `deviceScanner` never even finds my receiver device.

My `viewController` code is:

```
class ChromeCastViewController: UIViewController, GCKDeviceScannerListener, GCKDeviceManagerDelegate, GCKMediaControlChannelDelegate{

fileprivate let kCancelTitle = "Cancel"
fileprivate let kDisconnectTitle:String! = "Disconnect"
// Publicly available receiver to demonstrate sending messages - replace this with your
// own custom app ID.
fileprivate let kReceiverAppID = "XXXXXXXXX"
fileprivate lazy var btnImage:UIImage = {
    return UIImage(named: "icon-cast-identified.png")!
}()
fileprivate lazy var btnImageselected:UIImage = {
    return UIImage(named: "icon-cast-connected.png")!
}()

fileprivate var deviceScanner:GCKDeviceScanner?
fileprivate var deviceManager:GCKDeviceManager?
fileprivate var mediaInformation:GCKMediaInformation?
fileprivate var selectedDevice:GCKDevice?
@IBOutlet weak var googleCastButton: UIBarButtonItem!


@IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func backAction(_ sender: Any) {
     dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.startScan()

}

func startScan() {

    let filterCriteria = GCKFilterCriteria(forAvailableApplicationWithID: kReceiverAppID)
    self.deviceScanner = GCKDeviceScanner(filterCriteria: filterCriteria)
    if let deviceScanner = self.deviceScanner {
        deviceScanner.add(self)
        deviceScanner.startScan()
        print("scanning started")
        deviceScanner.passiveScan = true
    }
}


// MARK: GCKDeviceScannerListener

func deviceDidComeOnline(_ device: GCKDevice) {
    print("deviceDidComeOnline")
    print("Device found: \(device.friendlyName)");
    self.updateButtonStates()

}

func deviceDidGoOffline(_ device: GCKDevice) {
    print("deviceDidGoOffline()")
    print("Device went away: \(device.friendlyName)");
    self.updateButtonStates()

}

func deviceDidChange(_ device: GCKDevice) {
    print("deviceDidChange()");
}


    func updateButtonStates() {
        print("updateButton")
        if (deviceScanner!.devices.count > 0) {
            // Show the Cast button.
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [googleCastButton!]
            if (deviceManager != nil && deviceManager?.connectionState == GCKConnectionState.connected) {
                // Show the Cast button in the enabled state.
                googleCastButton!.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            } else {
                // Show the Cast button in the disabled state.
                googleCastButton!.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            }
        } else{
            // Don't show Cast button.
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = []
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help or tips you can give me.

Best regards

UPDATE:

I have modified my code base to follow google v3 guidelines.
I now instantiate a `GCKCastContext` in AppDelegate in order to use google widgets.
But It seems that `GCKCastContext` or functionalities associated with the singleton are never called after initialising it. I have tried to add the `GCKDiscoveryManagerListener` to my AppDelegate to see if  was detecting my ChromeCast device.

The code for my AppDelegate is :

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GCKLoggerDelegate,GCKDiscoveryManagerListener {

var window: UIWindow?
 fileprivate let kReceiverAppID = "XXXXXXXXXX"
var discoveryManager: GCKDiscoveryManager


override init(){

    let options:GCKCastOptions = GCKCastOptions(receiverApplicationID: kReceiverAppID)

    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
    self.discoveryManager = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().discoveryManager

    super.init()

    self.discoveryManager.add(self)
    self.discoveryManager.passiveScan = true
    self.discoveryManager.startDiscovery()
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}

.....

func log(fromFunction function: UnsafePointer<Int8>, message: String) {
    let functionName = String(cString: function)
    print(functionName + " - " + message);
}

func didUpdateDeviceList() {
    print("didUpdateDeviceList with \(discoveryManager.deviceCount) devices")
    (0..<discoveryManager.deviceCount).forEach { index in
        print(index, discoveryManager.device(at: index))
    }
}

func didStartDiscoveryForDeviceCategory(deviceCategory: String) {
    print("GCKDiscoveryManagerListener: \(deviceCategory)")

    print("FOUND: \(self.discoveryManager.hasDiscoveredDevices)")
}

func willUpdateDeviceList(){
    print("will update device was called")
}

}
```

The functions `didUpdateDeviceList`, `didStartDiscoveryForDeviceCategory`
, `willUpdateDeviceList` are never called, meaning no Chrome device is ever found making the widgets unusable.

Thank again for any help

Comment: Have you looked at the v3 iOS SDK? Then you don't have to use these low level classes and instead use the SDK widgets.

Comment: @LeonNicholls I have been following the v3 tutorials with no success. Could you be more explicit about the widgets, please, I don't really know what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate#the_cast_ux_widgets

Comment: @LeonNicholls Thanks Leon. I have read theses docs severals times now and tried to modify my code based on the new widgets but I still face problems while trying to use the google cast sdk. I have updated my original post to describe the new problems I'm facing.

Comment: I'm having an issue where the googlecast button won't show, getting these errors.

Device cache file file:///Users/alex/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CD9ABACD-E2F7-45A2-918E-C5B07C550A0E/data/Containers/Data/Application/FE8CFE49-73DC-4C80-AFDE-8FC109B060AC/Library/Caches/gck_nearby_devices.plist doesn't exist.

Device cache file file:///Users/alex/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CD9ABACD-E2F7-45A2-918E-C5B07C550A0E/data/Containers/Data/Application/FE8CFE49-73DC-4C80-AFDE-8FC109B060AC/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v1.plist doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlexanderMacleod I stoped seeking for a solution for now. If you find any solution it would be great if you could shared it. Thank again and good luck.

Comment: @Martin just started building my project in the CastVideos swift project that google put out. seems to be working fine.

Comment: have you add "import GoogleCast"?

Comment: Also, have you tried to enable "access wifi information" in "signing & capablities"?